# MySQL uniqueness of value

Tags: mysql, key, constraints, unique

I have a table that contains the columns:

```
employer_id
contact_id
primary
```

First two are integers, last is a tinyint that's either 1/0.  An employer can be joined to multiple contacts and vice versa.  However, I want to enforce that there can only be one instance where primary = 1 for each a particular employer.  There can be many where primary = 0.

Is there any way to do this through the use of constraints/keys in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not through keys, but you can set an insertion/update trigger to check that `(count(*) where primary=1 and employer_id=?) <= 1`.

Edit: Actually, I think there is a way: you make a second table with `employer_id` as the primary key and a second field for his primary contact. So you'd have these 2 tables:

```
===================================   ================================
|          maintable              |   |       maincontacttable       |
===================================   ================================
|employer_id|contact_id|...data...|   |employer_id|primary_contact_id|
|   PK      |    FK    |          |   |    PK FK  |       FK         |
===================================   ================================
```

No more `primary` column. Since `employer_id` is a key in the second table, you can have at most one entry.

You get the primary contact through a left outer join and it returns either the primary contact or `null`.

Comment: Right, I know I can do it with a trigger...was just hoping to avoid that.  Leaving open for now in case someone has some incredibly clever solution.  If not, I'll just accept my fate...and your response.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case a few days ago, and what I did was add one more columns "created_at", this way I can retrieve the "primary" (the last one inserted and with primary = 1);